# SQL Database access from a WebJob in Azure simple code

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to write a Azure Webjob to insert a record into a Azure SQL. 
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("runing... "+ DateTime.Now.ToString());
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureDB"].ConnectionString;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTest] ([CreateTime]) VALUES (GETDATE ( ))", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

At the beginning, I just had a Console.WriteLine code which worked fine but just after adding the codes related to reading the connectionstring and data it failed.

Do we need to upload the ddls?

Comment: Have a look at your error logs for the job - what errors do you see? You can find a link to your job history logs in the portal (see the "View the job history" section [in this help page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)).

Comment: There is not much there. Just this error which is very general: 
Job failed due to exit code -2146232576

Comment: That usually indicates a .NET assembly / runtime load failure. What .NET version are you targeting? See this forum post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e4ec7c82-8e87-41ab-ac06-2ba6362d141c/webjob-executable-cannot-be-started-failed-due-to-exit-code-2146232576) for more info.

Comment: The target framework is 4.6.1. Do we need to upload referenced DLLs? I've uploaded system.configuration.dll and system.data.dll but still same error.

Comment: As an experiment, do you see the same error if you downgrade from 4.6.1 to 4.6?

Comment: Thanks  @mathewc, that worked. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure WebApps do not yet support .NET version **4.6.1**. That framework version is not yet installed on the hosting VMs. It should be supported in the next couple months, but isn't yet. In the mean time, if you change your WebJob to target **4.6** it will work.